# javascript date comparison

Tags: javascript, date

I have `lead_creat_date` and I need to compare it against 20 days before date ( let's say today is aug-4-2011, than I need july-14-2011). So comparison against `lead_creat_date` and July-14-2011.

```
if ( lead_creat_date > july-14-2011) 
{

 alert('lead_creat_date is greater');

}
```

How can I do this comparison in JavaScript?

I'm trying using the JavaScript date object. I did get one number for 20 days before date, using `setDate()` & `getDate()` function but I don't know how to convert `lead_creat_date` into a JavaScript date() object.

Thanks.

Comment: What data type is `lead_creat_date`? A string, in the form “month-dd-year”?

Comment: It is a string "8/27/2009 10:23:00 AM".

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you can use the [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method.

It really depends on your date format.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume lead_creat_date is a Date object, seeing as it's not clear...

It depends on how accurate you need to be. You can do something like this, which will go back exactly 20 days, to the millisecond.

```
var now = new Date().getTime() - 20 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

if (lead_creat_date > now) {
    alert('lead_creat_date is greater');
}
```

If you only care about the day, you could probably do this

```
var now = new Date().getTime() - 20 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
now = new Date(now.toDateString());

if (lead_creat_date > now) {
    alert('lead_creat_date is greater');
}
```

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: “I'll assume lead_creat_date is a Date object, seeing as it's not clear...” — I think the last sentence makes it clear that it’s not: “I don't know how to convert lead_creat_date into a JavaScript date() object.”

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: Missed that portion. Well, I guess it depends on how he has it formatted then. If it isn't the proper format to pop into the `Date` constructor, it'll take some additional code. I'll leave this here until we find out what he has to work with.

Comment: Guys, lead_creat_date is not a Date Object. It's string "8/27/2009 10:23:00 AM".

Comment: @user659469: That's a valid JS Date string, just add `lead_creat_date = new Date(lead_creat_date)` before the if statement

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a date, convert the parts to numbers to use as input to the *Date* constructor. e.g. if your date is *July-14-2011* then you can convert it using:

```
var dateString = 'July-14-2011';
var months = {january:0, february:1, march:2, april:3, 
              may:4, june:5, july:6, august:7, september:8,
              october:9, november:10, december:11};

var dateBits = dateString.split('-');
var monthNumber = months[dateBits[0].toLowerCase()];

// Date object for date string
var date = new Date(dateBits[2], monthNumber, dateBits[1]);

// 20 days prior
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 20); // 24 Jun 2011
```

#### Edit

If your date format is 8/27/2009 10:23:00 AM the you can convert to a date using:

```
var dateString = '8/3/2011 10:23:00 AM';
var dateBits = dateString.split(/[ \/]/);    
var date = new Date(dateBits[2], dateBits[0] - 1, dateBits[1]);
// 20 days prior
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 20); // 14 Jul 2011

alert(date);
```

If you need to include the time, you can include it using the same strategy, e.g.

```
var dateString = '8/3/2011 10:23:00 AM';
var dateBits = dateString.split(/[ \/:]/);

if (dateBits[6].toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
    dateBits[3] = +dateBits[3] + 12;
}

// Thu 14 Jul 2011 10:23:00
var date = new Date(dateBits[2], dateBits[0] - 1, dateBits[1] - 20,
                    dateBits[3], dateBits[4], dateBits[5]);
```

and as a function:

```
function offsetDate(dateString, offset) {
  var dateBits = dateString.split(/[ \/:]/);

  if (dateBits[6].toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
      dateBits[3] = +dateBits[3] + 12;
  }

  return new Date(dateBits[2], dateBits[0] - 1, 
                  +dateBits[1] + +offset, 
                  dateBits[3], dateBits[4], dateBits[5]);
}

// Thu 14 Jul 2011 10:23:00
alert(offsetDate('8/3/2011 10:23:00 AM', -20));
// Tue 23 Aug 2011 22:23:00
alert(offsetDate('8/3/2011 10:23:00 PM', +20));
// Wed 18 Jan 2012 10:23:00
alert(offsetDate('12/29/2011 10:23:00 AM', +20));
```