# Weird / odd error with jQuery validation on end date is greater than start date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

I am currently using jQuery validation plugin to validate my form fields, named "start date" and "end date". I have my own jQuery validation method that will validate and ensure that the end date will be greater than the start date. However, the **weird thing** is that if my **start date is: 01/06/2017** and my **end date is: 01/05/2018**, it will prompt me an error saying that "end date should be greater than start date". **However, this error should not appear** because clearly end date is greater than start date by looking at the values. So what is wrong?

```
<form id="dataForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="startDateInput">Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="input-group date" style="max-width: 280px" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDateInput" name="startDateInput">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="endDateInput">End Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="input-group date" style="max-width: 280px" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDateInput" name="endDateInput">

            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$('.date').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});

$.validator.addMethod("endDate", function (value, element, params) {
    var startDate = $('#startDateInput').val();
    var endDate = value;
    return startDate < endDate || value == "";
}, '*End date must be after start date');

$('#dataForm').validate({
    rules: {
        startDateInput: {
            required: true
        },
        endDateInput: {
            endDate: true
        }
    }
});

$('#saveButton').on('click', function () {

    if ($('#dataForm').valid() == true)
        alert('hi');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/gud7xjy0/31/
Hi, please demo with the following values, start date: 01/06/2017
end date: 01/05/2018

Comment: Your rule is simply comparing the raw value of two fields.  In your case, the value of `01/05/2018` is considered text, not a number where you can do a "less than" comparison operation.  You need to convert the date into a mathematical value before doing the comparison.

Comment: Also see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948450/javascript-date-comparison?s=1|128.2217